# Entering scopes in template lib

Tags: c++, qt, qmake

In a C++/Qt project, we are using .pro-files and qmake to build. Part of the project is a static lib. The .pro file goes like this:

```
TEMPLATE = lib
CONFIG = staticlib

#general build instructions

linux{
    #some os-specific build instructions
}
win32|win64{
    #some os-specific build instructions
}
```

However, these scopes are never entered, not on a linux system (when the first scope should execute), nor on a windows system (for the second scope).

This only appears to be a problem in the staticlib-configuration/lib-template.

The Qt-[documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmake-project-files.html) mentions the different templates, but I do not see anything mentioned as to why scopes would not work or how to solve this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those conditions are true if they're set in the `CONFIG` variable. By overwriting `CONFIG` with `staticlib`, you reset all preset flags, including the ones specifying the platform.

It should work if you do `CONFIG += staticlib`